# How to find the average progress (per level) in a hierarchical tasks tree with PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, tree, ltree

I´m trying to determine the average progress of each *task group* in a *tasks* tree. The problem is that only the leaf nodes (which are in a diferent table ‒ a child table ‒) actually have the **progress** field.

I have a **Tasks** (parent) table and an **Activities** (child) table. Both of them share IDs. I should point out that I´m using the **ltree** extension in my DB.

I´m trying to make a view showing the entire tree and a column with the average progress *per node level*. I have to start the calculations from the inner-most level and build my way up in the tree structure, but I can´t seem to get it right.

I´ve tried to approach this using **recursive CTEs** and **window functions** to no avail. Postgres doesn´t allow to use aggregate functions in the *recursive term* of a *recursive cte*, so that didn´t work.

These are my tables (simplified):

```
tasks:
=======
id -- SERIAL
parent_id -- INTEGER
project_id -- INTEGER
name -- VARCHAR
task_group -- BOOL
path -- LTREE

activities:
===========
id -- INTEGER
progress -- INTEGER
```

**EDIT**

This is a screenshot of the view as of right now. I´m able to get the average progress of **all leaf nodes**, but that´s not exactly what I need. The average progress should be calculated for each level in the tree, and then build it´s way up in the node hierarchy.

[image: Tasks table]

Any insight on this will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the content of `progress` and how should progress be calculated for upper nodes?

Comment: Progress is a simple percentage.

Comment: Each task group (node) should calculate the average progress percentage of its immediate children, which, in time, calculated *their* progress from the average of *their* immediate children's progress.

Comment: It would be helpful to see some sample data plus the desired outcome.

Comment: I just edited my question with a screenshot of the table as it´s displayed at the moment and a comment on how it *should* display the average progress.

Comment: What is the connection between `tasks` and `activities`?

Comment: Activities is another table (not shown in the screenshot) wich actually holds the progress values. It works as a "child" or "detailed" table of Tasks joined by IDs. But I think that´s irrelevant for the problem at hand. Even using just 1 table (the one in my edit) the problem remains the same: **task group** average progress should be calculated *after* the average progress of its immediate child nodes has been calculated, and so forth. Hence the need for a recursive query, in my opinion, and posibly a window function.

Comment: How should I write a query like that if I don't know ho to find the progress that belongs to a task?

Comment: It´s simple... A **task** (leaf node) has **activities**. Each activity has a progress. The **task** progress is the average progress of its activities. But again, nevermind the 2 tables... The reason I'm struggling with this is that I can't get the average to work as an upward cascade. I can easily calculate the average of the leaf nodes, but since the tree could have an infinite depth, in theory, I need to calculate each level's average progress in order to find its parent's average progress.

Comment: I am afraid this is too complicated for me; sorry.